# Jenkins - Posting results to a external monitoring job is adding garbage to the build job log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a external monitor job that I'm pushing the result of another job to it with curl and base on this link :

[Monitoring external jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs)

After I create the job I just need to run a curl command with the body encoded in HEX to the specified url and then a build will be created and the output will be added to it but what I get instead is part of my output in clear text and the rest in weird characters like so :

```
Started
Asking akamai to purge this urls:
http://xxx/sites/all/modules/custom/uk.png     http://aaaaaasites/all/modules/custom/flags/jp.png
<html><head><title>401 Unauthorized</title>    </h�VC��&�G����CV�WF��&��VC�������R&R��BWF��&��VBF�66W72F�B&W6�W&6S�����&�G�����F����F�RW&�F �6�V6�7FGW2�bF�R&WVW7B�2��F�RF��RF�v�B�2��6�Ɩ�r&6�w&�V�B��"F�6�V6�7FGW2�bF�RF�6�W@�v�F��rf�"���F�W&vRF��6O request please keep in mind this is an estimated time
Waiting for another 60 seconds
Asking akamai to purge this urls:
...
..
..
```

This is how I'm doing it :

```
export output=`cat msg.out|xxd -c 256 -ps`

curl -k -X POST -d "<run><log encoding=\"hexBinary\">$output</log><result>0</result>  <duration>2000</duration></run>" https://$jenkinsuser:$jenkinspass@127.0.0.1/jenkins/job/akamai_purge_results/postBuildResult -H'.crumb:c775f3aa15464563456346e'
```

If I cat that file is all fine and even if I edit it with vi I can't see any problem with it.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this ?

Could it be a problem with the hex encoding ? ( I tried hex/enc/dec pages with the result of xxd and they look fine)

Thanks.

Comment: Tried some other encoding/decoding tools, same problem...I can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and stumbled across this: http://blog.markfeeney.com/2010/01/hexbinary-encoding.html

From that page, you can get the encoding you need via this command:

`echo "Hello world" | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"'
48656c6c6f20776f726c640a`

An excerpt from the explanation:

> So what the hell is that? -v means don't suppress any duplicate data
>   in the output, and -e is the format string. hexdump's very particular
>   about the formatting of the -e argument; so careful with the quotes.
>   The 1/1 means for every 1 byte encountered in the input, apply the
>   following formatting pattern 1 time. Despite this sounding like the
>   default behaviour in the man page, the 1/1 is not optional. /1 also
>   works, but the 1/1 is very very slightly more readable, IMO. The
>   "%02x" is just a standard-issue printf-style format code.

So in your case, you would do this (removing 'export' in favor of inline variable)

`` OUTPUT=`cat msg.out | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x"'` curl -k -X POST -d "<run><log encoding=\"hexBinary\">$OUTPUT</log><result>0</result>  <duration>2000</duration></run>" https://$jenkinsuser:$jenkinspass@127.0.0.1/jenkins/job/akamai_purge_results/postBuildResult -H'.crumb:c775f3aa15464563456346e' ``

Comment: Nice answer!  FYI, I mixed this together into an example cron script with Jenkins monitoring @ http://steve-jansen.github.io/blog/2014/11/20/how-to-use-jenkins-to-monitor-cron-jobs/